# Uncaught ReferenceError: for JS library on Android Project

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Trying to create a demo app using the [VAST Client JS library](https://github.com/dailymotion/vast-client-js) in my Android Project.

For this, I have downloaded the library's [pre-bundled version](https://github.com/dailymotion/vast-client-js#browser-script)

[image: JS library document]

and put it in the assets folder.

[image: Assets folder]

Besides that, I've also created an HTML file that basically calls the JS functions of the library.

```
< !DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src='file:///android_asset/vast-client-browser-min.js'></script>
<script>
 // Get the VAST Url from the Java class
 const tagURL = window.MyHandler.getVASTUrl();
 
 const vastClient = new VAST.VASTClient();

 vastClient.get(tagURL)
 .then(res => {
    // notify my Java class
    window.MyHandler.onResponse('hey');
 }).catch(err => {
    // notify my Java class
     window.MyHandler.onError('heyy');
 });
</script>
</head>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

On the Java side, I call my HTML file

```
    // initialize webview
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    
    // add javascript interface to notify my java class from the JS side.
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this, webView), "MyHandler");
    
    // Load the HTML file
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/vast_client_handler.html");
```

However, when I run the app, I get this;

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(17)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: VASTClient is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/vast_client_handler.html (17)
```

what could I be missing? Thanks

Comment: If my answer helped you than I would appreciate if you accept it

Answer (score 0):

Your whole HTML document is wrong.

- First, you should start with the `<html>` tag and not the `<head>` tag.
- The `< !DOCTYPE html>` has a space after the first `<` character so it doesn't get parsed properly
- You have a closing  tag after the script, but the script should be inside
- This is just a suggestion - but if you're loading a resource in the head, you should properly put the script that uses it inside the `body` so that you won't have race conditions (`<head>` content loads before the `<body>`)